# How to Create Half Round Button in Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am developing my app but i don't know how to half round button create in android and this button size is 50% and around 5 button and textview .How to create layout in android app .And this layout static no animation added in layout How to possible ?Please Help me!!My image Below!!
[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: this is simple get the half image of button and setbackground to button.

Comment: but i set half image on button but how to set around button and text view not set properly. @raj

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [ArcMEnu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)
it gives you something simillar to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu) Library. This Library is Exactly What you want.**CIRCLE MENU**  & MODIFIY IT aCCORDING tO YOUR NEED . Hope this Help You.

Answer (score 0):

*android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"*

set marginleft in youe xml file 50 is just example for 100 dp width...
try with your half width